# C# DataGridView with Identity Column

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-express

I am using Visual Studio 2010, language C# and SQL Server Express Edition as backend. There is one form with DataGridView control, I've setup columns manually using designer, then on runtime set the data source.

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
sqlConnection.Open();
String sqlSelectDet = "Select OrdDetID, OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity from OrderDetails"; 

//===============================================================================
//--- Set up the INSERT Command OrderDetails
//===============================================================================

sDetInsProcName = "prInsert_OrderDetail";
insertcommandDet = new SqlCommand(sDetInsProcName, sqlConnection);
insertcommandDet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add("@nNewDetID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "OrdDetID");
insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add("@nOrderID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "OrderID");
insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add("@nProductID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ProductID");
insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add("@mUnitPrice", SqlDbType.Money, 8, "UnitPrice");
insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add("@nQuantity", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 2, "Quantity");

sqlDataDet.InsertCommand = insertcommandDet;
```

As code mentioned, I am using a stored procedure `prInsert_OrderDetail`. The `OrdDetID` is a sort of LineItem number, which is autoincrement field in the database.

For setting up DataGridView I am using following:

```
dtDet = new DataTable();
dtDet.Clear(); 
sqlDataDet.FillSchema(dtDet, SchemaType.Source);

ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dtDet);

ds.Tables[1].Columns["OrdDetID"].AutoIncrement = true;
ds.Tables[1].Columns["OrdDetID"].AutoIncrementSeed = -1;
ds.Tables[1].Columns["OrdDetID"].AutoIncrementStep = -1;

bsDet = new BindingSource();
bsDet.DataSource = ds;
bsDet.DataMember = "OrderDetails"; 

// Name of DataGridView Control is dgInvDet
dgInvDet.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgInvDet.DataSource = bsDet;
dgInvDet.Columns["OrdDetID"].DataPropertyName = "OrdDetID";
dgInvDet.Columns["OrderID"].DataPropertyName = "OrderID";
dgInvDet.Columns["ProductID"].DataPropertyName = "ProductID";
dgInvDet.Columns["UnitPrice"].DataPropertyName = "UnitPrice";
dgInvDet.Columns["Quantity"].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
```

In the Save button click event, following code is use to save the data from DataGridView to Database:

```
sqlDataDet.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
```

The stored procedure in SQL Server is this:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[prInsert_OrderDetail]
@nOrderID INT, 
@nProductID INT, 
@mUnitPrice MONEY, 
@nQuantity SMALLINT,
@nNewDetID INT OUTPUT
AS 
INSERT INTO [OrderDetails] (OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity)
VALUES (@nOrderID, @nProductID, @mUnitPrice, @nQuantity)

    SET @nNewDetID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Data is saved in database correctly, my problem is how can I get `OrdDetID` actual identity values, dataGridView doesn't shows actual values in DataGridView after records are inserted in database. Because what I am getting is -1, -2, -3 and so on due to the settings of column.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks

Ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter

```
insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add("@nNewDetID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "OrdDetID");
```

Needs to be specified as **ParameterDirection.Output**, i.e. something like the following lines of code :

```
    SqlParameter pID = new SqlParameter("nNewDetID", DBType.Int32, 4);
    pID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add(pID);
    //** other code here...
    insertcommandDet.ExecuteScalar();
```

After you execute your command, you extract the value by

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["nNewDetID"].Value.ToString());
```

You should be able to test this in a console application, to get you going...

```
            // set connection
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("[Your connection string here]");

            // open connection
            sqlConnection.Open();

            // specify the stored procedure which has an output parameter, namely "NewId"
            SqlCommand insertcommandDet = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[TestingSP]", sqlConnection);

            // tell the command that it is a stored procedure
            insertcommandDet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // add the parameter having the name
            insertcommandDet.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name","Test Name"); 

            // this parameter will contain the new id after
            SqlParameter pID = new SqlParameter("NewId", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            pID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            // add the parameter to the command
            insertcommandDet.Parameters.Add(pID);

            // execute command with ExecuteScalar()
            insertcommandDet.ExecuteScalar();

            // Get parameter value extracted with ExecuteScalar
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(insertcommandDet.Parameters["NewId"].Value.ToString());
```

The procedure I used is the following

```
create  PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestingSP](
@Name varchar(50) ,
@NewId INT OUTPUT)
AS 
INSERT INTO [Testing]
select @name
    SET @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: thanks for reply,  where should I put insertcommandDet.ExecuteScaler()? In save button click event? Or where i 've setup the InsertCommand?

Comment: and also should I use sqlDataDet.Update statement which I am using in click button event at present after changing the code you have suggested?

Comment: Thanks again for reply, please forgive the stupidity of an beginner...but do the code work with DataGridView, I mean how do OrdDetID will get actual id (from int ID code)..? In DataGridView user will enter Details for more then one products like OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice & Quantity, end for each record that entered will generate a OrdDetID, that is why I am confuse with the code...

Comment: In the button click event, you can see what the user has entered and then use the code above as a guide.

Comment: Thanks I will try it and let you know.